# Kibana apm dashboard error: The aggregations key is missing from the response, check your permissions for this request

Tags: elastic-stack, elk, apm

I am getting below error when I load the APM dashboard.
I can see the request log and server stats in APM, however, the dashboard is not getting displayed.

[image]

Comment: for someone having the same issue.
for me the fix was to update to the latest version, i was using very old version of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone having the same issue. for me the fix was to update to the latest version, I was using a very old version of Kibana and the lastest version of Elastic search.